# php database register and accepting

Tags: php, mysql, database, web, authentication

So i am attempting to make a php page for new users to make an account to log into the website. But i don't want just any one making an account. So in turn i want users to register but with an approval of a staff member. the only code i found is to duplicate but not a webpage that list the name number ect. and then i can choose to add them to the log in.
Here is the code i use to register them.

So i have a database for applicants and one for accepted but i want only the ones on the list of applicants to be added over. How would i view the list then pick and submit the accepted people.

```
<?php 

require("auth_common.php"); 

if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
    { 
        die("Please enter a username."); 
    } 

    if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
    { 
        die("Please enter a password."); 
    } 

    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    { 
        die("Invalid E-Mail Address"); 
    } 

    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 

    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    if($row) 
    { 
        die("This username is already in use"); 
    } 

    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            email = :email 
    "; 

    $query_params = array( 
        ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    if($row) 
    { 
        die("This email address is already registered"); 
    } 

    $query = " 
        INSERT INTO users ( 
            username, 
            password, 
            salt, 
            email 
        ) VALUES ( 
            :username, 
            :password, 
            :salt, 
            :email 
        ) 
    "; 

    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 

    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
    { 
        $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
    } 

    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
        ':password' => $password, 
        ':salt' => $salt, 
        ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 

        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    header("Location: login.php"); 

    die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
} 
?> 
<h1>Register</h1> 
<form action="register.php" method="post"> 
    Username:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    E-Mail:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Password:<br /> 
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Register" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience it is far easier to just add an extra field to the users table called "status" which can be an enum with ("approved", "unapproved")

EDIT: Attempt at making it understandable:

First you have a table, which in essence will resemble this:

```
+--+--------+--------+----------+
|id|username|password|status    |
+-------------------------------+
| 1|dennis  |ezpwlol |unapproved|
+-------------------------------+
| 2|otherguy|hardpw! |approved  |
+--+--------+--------+----------+
```

Then you will want to find out what users are unapproved, so you run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users where status = 'unapproved';
```

The result from the above example will be:

```
+--+--------+--------+----------+
|id|username|password|status    |
+-------------------------------+
| 1|dennis  |ezpwlol |unapproved|
+-------------------------------+
```

Using PHP you can loop the result into a list with usernames and a button:

Dennis [ACCEPT] <<-- Button will lead to page or route and will pass the id of the user to accept.

On that page or route you will run an update query for that user:

```
UPDATE users SET status = 'approved' WHERE id = {THE ID PASSED TO THE PAGE};
```

Now that user will have it's status set to approved, and thus not appear anymore in your unapproved list.

Comment: That would be a lot easier. But how could i make it so where a webpage would display the users with lets say a button to accept and reject(delete them from the db) the users.

Comment: You would create a query for the Users table where you would select only the users where status equals unapproved. That would be your list  of unapproved users. Then render it with the corresponding buttons, and  when one of the buttons is clicked, you would query an update statement for that record changing unapproved to approved

Comment: Try not to overcomplicate things as you do programming. Keep it simple and neat. Way easier to modify or enhance code later on. Also easier to read through.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry i'm still vary new to this but with the edit above I think i get it! Thanks again